# Above ground burial

Tags: halacha, funeral-burial-levaya, cemetery-grave

Is an above-ground burial halachically acceptable? For example, I've seen multi-story graves that look like a parking garage and tombs that are carved into the side of a mountain.

Comment: Interesting question. The cemetery that my father-in-law a"h is buried in has a huge section of above-ground "vaults". They are in a "hallway". It looks weird to me. When I was there last time, there was a huge sign explaining that above-ground burials were rabbinically approved. I didn't have time to read it, thoroughly, so I can't say which rabbis approved this. Perhaps, their web site has more info on it.

Comment: see Baba batra, nazir, ohalot

Comment: What about ancient tombs?

Comment: AFAIUI, these are technically below ground. Concrete is basically a form of rock (artificial, but still rock). It forms a continuum with the ground itself and so becomes an extension of it. In the same way as burials were made in caves and niches about 2000 years ago (e.g. Bet Shearim), the building is an artificial cave. It seems strange to us because we are used to "field burial (kvurat sadeh)".  http://www.kadisha.biz/showItem.aspx?levelId=59851 gives somes details of the types of burial permitted

Comment: @Epicentre Thank you for the link, helps a lot.

Comment: How to properly implement _carved into the side of a mountain_ is mentioned in various Mishnayot. So that's not a good question; obviously it's OK. The _multi-story graves that look like a parking garage_ is a good question.

Comment: @DannySchoemann I've seen you other posts and they seem decent so I'll break from my usual custom of ignoring comments. The concept of "good question" or not is kind of ridiculous. Someone is seeking knowledge, for him it's a good question. Especially if you need to resort to a mishna to prove your point. This is a major problem with this exchange which turns people off from using it.

Comment: @Moses613 - My apologies; I was thinking out loud at my keyboard; admittedly a bad habit.

Comment: @moses613 You're right that to the poster the question is probably a good one. But you're confusing good questions with good question posts, and the terminology blurs that distinction. You could really want to know the answer but if you don't present your question clearly and precisely with basic background research etc. then you have presented an objectively bad question post. It should be downvoted. Many people are indeed turned off by realizing this site isn't a free for all where they can be exempt from any effort and get all the free service they want from experts. Cant please everyone...

Comment: @DanF re your very first comment above, does the cemetery look anything like the picture in my answer below or the third picture in [this article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2797118/cities-dead-israel-turns-high-rises-cemeteries-approval-rabbis-artificial-caves.html#ixzz5GFQ7X6on) ? If you happen to go back it would be super interesting to take a picture from the approbations

Comment: @mbloch It doesn't look like this at all. The best comparison is that it looks like a giant room with several rows of vaults that look like giant bank safe deposit boxes. Except that instead of money and documents, if you were to pull out the vault, you'd find a large wooden box, and while there might be money inside, there's a corpse next to his money.

Answer (score 10):

Yes above-ground burial is halachically acceptable if done properly.

For instance Israel suffers a lack of enough burial space and has developed a number of high-capacity above-ground "burial buildings". To respect the halachic requirement to be buried in earth (see [this other answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93314/11501)), these buildings are built with vertical building columns filled with earth, connecting every floor with the ground.

I saw today such a large cemetery near Petach Tikva called the Yarkon Cemetery:
[image]

The DailyMail (!) [reports](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2797118/cities-dead-israel-turns-high-rises-cemeteries-approval-rabbis-artificial-caves.html#ixzz5GFQ7X6on) on it

> R Yaakov Ruza, the rabbi of the Tel Aviv burial society, a semiofficial
>   organisation that oversees Jewish burials, said the new forms of
>   burial have been endorsed by leading Jewish ultra-Orthodox figures.
>
> The towers, for instance, have pipes filled with dirt inside their
>   columns so that each layer is still connected to the ground. In many
>   ways, Ruza said the new types of burial represent a return to the Holy
>   Land's ancient origins of burying inside caves and catacombs. "This is an artificial cave. Once they used to build a cave into a mountain. Now we are taking these artificial caves and turning them into a mountain."

[Elsewhere](https://www.jpost.com/Magazine/Close-to-the-sky-490467) R Yaakov Ruza expands

> People are always sensitive whenever small changes are made in burial
>   traditions, but the practice of burying deceased upon deceased has been approved
>   in Israel by all the main rabbis. There is a set of rules one must always take into
>   account when building multilevel cemeteries according to halachic
>   rulings. First, there must be a layer of at least 30 cm. of earth
>   between the dead, and second, this layer must be grounded in the soil
>   of Earth.

All Jewish cemeteries in Israel are under the responsibility of the (Orthodox) local rabbinates and are halachically kosher according to the Chief Rabbinate. Beyond the initial Petach Tikva location, these above-ground have now been built in Haifa, Herzlia and Kfar Saba (all highly-populated areas).

[This source](http://strangeside.com/cemeteries-caves-and-above-ground/) quotes a letter from the Chief Rabbinate

> After hearing of the scarcity of  land available for cemeteries in
>   Israel  and the suggestion of the architects  Uri Ponger and Tuviah
>   Sagiv to build  an above ground cemetery as included  with this, it
>   has been decided: Basically, there is no halachic objection to inter
>   in  this way, that is, in a cemetery building  within a hill of rising
>   earth, etc.

(see at the end of the latter article for more on opposition from some *haredi* poskim).

See also [here](https://www.timesofisrael.com/underground-cemetery-project-looks-to-the-past-for-the-graveyard-of-the-future/) and [here](https://www.theguardian.com/cities/2019/oct/18/the-future-of-burial-inside-jerusalems-hi-tech-underground-necropolis?utm_term=Autofeed&CMP=twt_gu&utm_medium=&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1571386072) for the latest "innovation" in high-density cemeteries which is a 3-level 12-tunnel underground cemetery below Har Hamenuhot in Jerusalem, modeled after ancient catacombs.

For further sources see R David Brofsky's Hilkhot Avelut p. 62 which notes many additional rabbis permitting (e.g., R Shlomo Amar, R Ovadia Yosef) and one objection from R Elyashiv.

Comment: At the time of Gemara there wereכוכים not on the ground but on the rock wall

Comment: These are incredibly expensive and inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

The Torah (Deuteronomy 21:22-23) says:

> וְכִי יִהְיֶה בְאִישׁ חֵטְא מִשְׁפַּט מָוֶת וְהוּמָת וְתָלִיתָ אֹתוֹ
>   עַל עֵץ לֹא תָלִין נִבְלָתוֹ עַל הָעֵץ כִּי קָבוֹר תִּקְבְּרֶנּוּ
>   בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא כִּי קִלְלַת אֱלֹהִים תָּלוּי וְלֹא תְטַמֵּא אֶת
>   אַדְמָתְךָ אֲשֶׁר ה' אֱלֹהֶיךָ נֹתֵן לְךָ נַחֲלָה
>
> And if a man have committed a sin worthy of death, and he be put to
>   death, and thou hang him on a tree; his body shall not remain all
>   night upon the tree, but thou shalt surely bury him the same day; for
>   he that is hanged is a reproach unto God; that thou defile not thy
>   land which the LORD thy God giveth thee for an inheritance. ([Mechon Mamre](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0521.htm))

The Talmud ([Sanhedrin 46b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=46b&format=pdf)) cites this as the Biblical source for burial, noting that one who does not bury a dead body violates a negative commandment:

> א"ר יוחנן משום ר"ש בן יוחי מנין למלין את מתו שעובר עליו בל"ת ת"ל כי
>   קבר תקברנו מכאן למלין את מתו שעובר בלא תעשה איכא דאמרי אמר רבי יוחנן
>   משום ר"ש בן יוחי רמז לקבורה מן התורה מניין ת"ל כי קבר תקברנו מכאן רמז
>   לקבורה מן התורה
>
> R. Johanan said on the authority of R. Simeon b. Yohai: Whence is it
>   inferred that whoever keeps his dead [unburied] over night
>   transgresses thereby a negative conmmand? — From the verse, Thou shalt
>   surely bury him; whence we learn that he who keeps his dead [unburied]
>   over night transgresses a prohibitory command. Others state: R.
>   Johanan said on the authority of R. Simeon b. Yohai: Where is burial
>   [as a means of disposing of the dead] alluded to in the Torah? — In
>   the verse, Thou shalt surely bury him: here we find an allusion to
>   burial in the Torah. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nezikin/Sanhedrin.pdf))

[Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) ([Hilchos Avel 12:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=14849)) codifies the law as follows:

> ההספד כבוד המת הוא לפיכך כופין את היורשין ליתן שכר מקוננים והמקוננות
>   וסופדין אותו ואם צוה שלא יספדוהו אין סופדין אותו אבל אם צוה שלא יקבר
>   אין שומעין לו שהקבורה מצוה שנאמר כי קבור תקברנו
>
> A eulogy is an honor for the deceased. Therefore we compel the heirs
>   to pay the wages of the men and women who recite laments and they
>   eulogize him. If the deceased directed that he not be eulogized, we do
>   not eulogize him. If, however, he directed that he not be buried, we
>   do not heed him, for burial is a mitzvah, as Deuteronomy 21:22 states:
>   "And you shall certainly bury him." ([Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1181893/jewish/Avel-Chapter-12.htm))

[R. Yaakov ben Asher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_ben_Asher) codifies this ([Tur Y.D. 362](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6517)) and explains that this means that one cannot simply put the body in a coffin and leave it somewhere; the body must specifically be placed in the ground:

> א"ר יוחנן מניין לקבורה מן התורה פירוש שצריך לקוברו בקרקע ולא יתננו
>   בארון ויניחנו כך ת"ל כי קבור תקברנו לפיכך הנותן מתו בארון ולא קברו
>   בקרקע עובר משום שמלין המת אלא צריך לקוברו בקרקע ואם עשה לו ארון וקברו
>   בקרקע אינו עובר עליו ומ"מ יפה לקוברו בארץ דקבורת ארץ ממש מצוה אפי'
>   בח"ל ובכל מקום ומקום לפי מנהגו יש קוברין בכוכין ויש בחפירות ויש בארון

[R. Yosef Karo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Karo) ([Shulchan Aruch Y.D. 362:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6936)) similarly codifies the law as requiring burial specifically in the ground:

> הנותן מתו בארון ולא קברו בקרקע עובר משום מלין את המת ואם נתנו בארון
>   וקברו בקרקע אינו עובר עליו ומכל מקום יפה לקברו בקרקע ממש אפילו בח"ל

[R. Mordechai Yaffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordecai_Yoffe) ([Levush Y.D. 362:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9276&st=&pgnum=346)) codifies this with a little more detail, and also notes that the Torah says that a man will "return to dust" which also implies burial in the ground:

> מצוה מן התורה לקבור את המת בקרקע שנאמר קבור תקברנו לרבות כל המתים
>   לקבורה  לפיכך הנותן מתו בארון ולא קברו בקרקע הרי זה עובר משום בל תלין
>   דהא לא קברו ואם נתנו בארון וקברו בקרקע אינו עובר עליו ומכל מקום יפה
>   לקוברו בקרקע ממש אפילו בחוצה לארץ דסתם קבור בארץ ממש משמע ועוד דנוח לו
>   למת יותר לשכב על העפר ממש שנאמר כי עפר אתה ואל עפר תשוב ומכאן תמיה
>   גדולה בעיני מה שאנו נוהגין לעשות לכהנים ארונות שלימים דהיינו שעושין
>   מלמטה דף ושוכב על הדף ואומרים טעם משום חשיבות דכהונה הוא והרי טוב היה
>   לו לשכב על העפר וכי משום חשיבתו עושין לו מה שאין לו נחת רוח בקברו ועוד
>   הרי רבינו הקדוש נשיא היה וצוה כן שתהא ארונו נקובה מלמטה שפירושו שיטלו
>   דף התחתון מן הארון וישכיבוהו על העפר וצריך עיון

[R. Yechiel Michel Epstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Epstein) ([Aruch Hashulchan Y.D. 362:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14244&st=&pgnum=552&hilite=)) also explicitly states that the Torah demands burial in the ground, citing both the verse mentioned by the Talmud as well as the verse mentioned by R. Mordechai Yaffe:

> בסנהדרין א"ר יוחנן מנין לקבורה מן התורה שנאמר כי קבור תקברנו כלומר
>   דשלא יהא המת מונח בגלוי דבר זה השכל מחייב וכל מין האנושי מודה בזה אלא
>   דלפי השכל די לסוגרו בארון של ברזל ולהניחו באיזה מרתף אבל התורה הקפידה
>   שגוף האדם יהיה טמון בקרקע כדכתיב ואל עפר תשוב ולכן הנותן מתו בארון ולא
>   קברו בקרקע עובר משום בל תלין ולכן כתיב בקרא דבל תלין קבור תקברנו לשון
>   כפול דדווקא בקרקע דמכי קבור בלבד הייתי אומר לקוברו בארון בלבד ולזה
>   כפלה התורה תקברנו ואם נתנו בארון וקברו בקרקע את הארון אינו עובר עליו

[R. Chaim Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Berlin) (Nishmas Chaim # 122 in the 1 volume edition) has a responsum in which he was asked about the source for burial in the ground as opposed to cremation. R. Berlin has quite a few paragraphs rejecting any possibility that burial is not required, and concludes by citing [R. Nissim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissim_of_Gerona) that we follow the (above mentioned) Talmud that burial in the ground is required because that is the ultimate form of hiding way the body:

> וזה לשון הר"ן בחידושיו לסנהדרין מ"ו ב' דקיי"ל כר' יוחנן משום רשב"י
>   וא"כ אין אדם יוצא ידי חובת קבורה אלא בקבורת קרקע ולא שתהא הקבורה ממש
>   בקרקע שלא יצא ידי חובתו אם יקבור ארונו בקרקע אלא הכוונה בקבורת קרקע
>   מפני שהוא תכלית הענין שאין לך גניזה גדולה ממנה וכן הי' מנהג התלמוד
>   בקבורת הכוכין שהיו נותנין שם את המת כשהוא מונח בארון אבל מפני שאמר
>   הכתוב כי עפר אתה ואל עפר תשוב ואמרו בהגדה שהעפר הוא רפואתו טוב לקיים
>   בו קבורת קרקע ממש שלא בהפסק וכן מנהגנו עכ"ל הר"ן בחידושיו

[R. Moshe Fenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein) ([Igros Moshe Y.D. 3:143](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&pgnum=414)) has a responsum in which he was asked about burial in a mausoleum. He responded by citing the Talmud, Tur, and Shulchan Aruch that there is an absolute requirement for burial in the ground.

> הנה ודאי שלבנות מאזאליאם (שהוא בנין עם כוכים שנבנו בו) להניח שם מתים
>   הוא איסור גדול דהא צריך לקבור דוקא בקרקע כמפורש בסנהדרין דף מ"ו ע"ב
>   מקרא דתקברנו שלא סגי להניחו בארון ואיפסק כן בטור וש"ע סימן שס"ב סע' א'
>   הנותן את מתו בארון ולא קברו בקרקע עובר משום מלין את המת

Towards the end he writes in very strong terms that anyone who puts a body in a mausoleum violates two great prohibitions every day, aside from the great sin of causing pain to the dead for which repentance doesn't help without seeking forgiveness from the dead:

> וממילא פשוט שחייבים לפרסם האיסור אשר שום איש מישראל אסור להניחו
>   במאזאליאם מהני תרי איסורים הגדולים עבירת לאו ועשה על כל יום ויום לבד
>   החטא הגדול שיצערו להמתים שאף תשובה לא יועיל עד שירצה את המת וימחול לו
>   דאין טעם שימחול לו על מה שהרע לו להכעיס בלא שום הנאה ותיאבון

[Professor Louis Ginzberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Ginzberg) has a whole bunch of responsa about burial, and he reiterates again and again that Jewish Law demands burial in the ground:

**[The Responsa of Professor Louis Ginzberg](https://books.google.com/books?id=r8uJAAAAMAAJ&dq=the%20responsa%20of%20professor%20louis%20ginzberg&source=gbs_similarbooks) Y.D. # 16**

> If my assumption is correct, of course, it would not be permitted, as,
>   according to Jewish Law, the coffin must be put into the ground and
>   into a structure.

**[The Responsa of Professor Louis Ginzberg](https://books.google.com/books?id=r8uJAAAAMAAJ&dq=the%20responsa%20of%20professor%20louis%20ginzberg&source=gbs_similarbooks) Y.D. # 18**

> Burial, as defined by Jewish Law, means placing the body into the
>   grave and not keeping it in a mausoleum.

Comment: All great sources but, as I'm sure you understand, "above ground" cemeteries in Israel are built by connecting the "floors" with the ground through columns of earth. That makes them halachically "in the ground". I say that because I'm not too sure what is the conclusion of your answer

Comment: @mbloch  The conclusion of my answer is that the consensus of codes and responsa is that burial in the ground is a biblically mandated commandment/prohibition, and therefore above-ground burial is not halachically acceptable. If someone wants to argue that a certain form of above-ground burial is not considered "above-ground" that is fine, but the burden is on him to justify that.

Comment: Thanks. I think there would be value in adding this summary at the very top as otherwise the conclusion is not so clear. And you will have understood the "above ground cemeteries" being discussed are physically above ground, but very much "within ground" halachically and have haskamot from the rabbanut. I +1'd already though

Answer (score 1):

According to [this chabad.org article](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281565/jewish/The-Interment.htm) the double reference in the torah to being buried 
1) "For dust thou are and unto dust shalt thou return." ([Genesis 3:19](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8167/jewish/Chapter-3.htm#v=19)) 
2)"Thou shalt surely bury him" ([Deuteronomy 21:23](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9985#v=23)) means you have to be buried in the ground.

However, it does give a few conditions in which way a person can be buried in a mausoleum, one of which is:

> A mausoleum is permissible only if the deceased is buried in the earth itself, and the mausoleum is built around the plot of earth.